# Server-side validation using spring boot and thymeleaf inside modal form

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I'm just learning into spring boot and thymeleaf, the one that i know is to do validation inside the modal form, without redirect it, just confuse at this step.

**My Class Model**

```
public class Class {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @NotBlank
    private String className;

    public Class(@NotEmpty @NotBlank String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }
}
```

**Html Fronted to show Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" th:fragment="modal-add" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Classroom</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <form th:action="@{/addclass}" th:object="${class}" method="post">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="className">Class Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="className" th:field="*{className}" placeholder="Name of Class">
                                <div class="text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('className')}" th:errors="*{className}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Class Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/addclass")
    public String addClass(@Valid @ModelAttribute("class") Class kelas, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            //what to do here ? to show error validation without closing modal?

        }else{
            classService.addClass(kelas);
        }
        return "redirect:/classlist";
    }
```

Comment: I not sure you can do that your way .But You can try with `ajax`

Comment: Return the name of the view you want to render (without `redirect:` and everything will be preserved. Also I would strongly suggest to come up with another name then `Class` for your class, as somewhere it will fail you and you will use the wrong class.

Answer (score 1):

Formvalidation in thymeleaf with an open modal is a little bit tricky. Here is my solution:

In your controller function add "RedirectAttributes atts".
Add the attribute hasErrors with the value true.

```
@PostMapping("/addclass")
public String addClass(@Valid @ModelAttribute("class") Class kelas, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes atts) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        atts.addAttribute("hasErrors", true);
        return "classlist";
    }else{
        classService.addClass(kelas);
    }
    return "redirect:/classlist";
}
```

In your html file you add conditional JS-Code with the th:inline and the th:if. So if any field has an error, the JS-Code will be executed. In the JS-Code you can open the modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" th:fragment="modal-add" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
           <script th:inline="javascript" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}">$("#addModal").modal("show");</script>
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Classroom</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <form th:action="@{/addclass}" th:object="${class}" method="post">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="className">Class Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="className" th:field="*{className}" placeholder="Name of Class">
                            <div class="text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('className')}" th:errors="*{className}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve; so this is generic answer based on your code. If there is any error, simply attach the error if you want to and return to original mapping only. It will not redirect to any other page and will show the error on web page. Sample code as per your code is -

```
@PostMapping("/addclass")
public String addClass(@ModelAttribute("class") @Valid Class kelas, BindingResult result) {
       if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "addClass";    
        }
        //else is not required here. If there are errors, it is returned before reaching here anyways.
        classService.addClass(kelas);
        return "redirect:/classlist";
}
```

Your html should be like (Only error part) -

```
<div class="text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('className')}" th:errors="*{className}">
      <p>Incorrect Class Name</p>
</div>
```

You can also specify the error messages in your modal class itself or application.properties or a final static class and send it along with response.

Few other points as you are new - Avoid using name as Class for class names. It will be confusing at later point and time and is not a good practice. Use some proper class name i.e. what this Modal class is supposed to represent.  secondly, I believe `@NotEmpty` and `@NotBlank` is not required at constructor too.

Comment: that result will redirect to the page again right? that i want to achieve is to keepthe modal and the error showed through thymeleaf

Comment: @jadugdestian it will be there until the request is complete. Did you try the changes I suggest? If you are facing any issue, can you paste screenshot to explain a lit bit more?

Comment: @jadugdestian Until you specifically redirect like the second return statement, the model and error will be available.

Comment: yeah that's mean the page will reload, and the modal will closed.

Comment: @jadugdestian yeah, if you refresh the page yourself, the model will likely to be gone. Is it part of your requirement? Otherwise, once the request comes back from server, you'll have model and error message.

Answer (score 0):

In method addClass you must return view look like.

```
 if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "login";
    }
```

Login is page you show login page. In login page you must handle error look like:

```
<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('className')}" th:errors="*{className}">Class name Error</span>
```